# Converting TSQL to Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Hi have the below query that I need to convert to LINQ(VB.net 10) and I am struggling to get the grouping right.

How do you term the LINQ query to have a a where clause on the child (tblApplicationAccess) and group the results on the parent table (tblBusinessUnit)?

**TSQL**

```
SELECT tblBusinessUnit.ID, tblBusinessUnit.Name 
    FROM tblBusinessUnit INNER JOIN tblApplicationAccess ON 
        tblBusinessUnit.ID = tblApplicationAccess.BUID 
    WHERE(tblApplicationAccess.ApplicationID = @AppID) 
    GROUP BY tblBusinessUnit.ID, tblBusinessUnit.Name ORDER BY [Name]
```

**Entity Model**

[image]

**Update**

OK, I have got it working but I have no idea if this is the best way to do this. Do I need to create the explicit join? Is this efficient?

```
Dim var = (From bu In hf.BusinessUnits
            Join app In hf.ApplicationAccesses On bu.ID Equals app.BUID
            Where app.ApplicationID.Equals(56)
            Group By bu.ID, bu.Name, bu.IsInternalSupplier Into Group
                Select New BusinessUnitModel With {.ID = ID,
                    .Name = Name,
                    .IsInternalSupplier = IsInternalSupplier}).ToList
```

Comment: It seems to me that the grouping is not necessary at all, you simply want the results to be ordered by Name, don't you?

Comment: I think I need to group the results as I want distinct items from the business unit table. I certainly need to do that in TSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the join in the Linq to Entities query when you start at the ApplicationAccess side and use the BussinessUnit Navigation property to get to the BussinessUnit entity. Also, the projection will be hierarchical in stead of flat. It is not said that this will be more efficient. Do some profiling and let us know!

```
Using context = New QuerySpikesdfEntities

   'Create the query using LINQ to Entities. No join is necessary as we use the Navigation property 'BussinessUnit'
    Dim projections = From entry In context.ApplicationAccessEntries
                      Where entry.ApplicationID = 56
                      Group By supplierKey = entry.BussinessUnit.IsInternalSupplier Into supplierGroup = Group
                      Select New With {
                         .IsInternalSupplier = supplierKey,
                         .Suppliers = From supplier In supplierGroup
                                      Order By supplier.BussinessUnit.Name
                                      Select New With
                                         {
                                           .ID = supplier.BussinessUnit.ID,
                                           .Name = supplier.BussinessUnit.Name
                                         }
                             }

  'It remains to be seen if the resulting query is more efficient than the one that used the Join
  'This will output the query to the Console.
  'Profile this query and the Join query using the Stopwatch class.
   Console.WriteLine(DirectCast(projections, ObjectQuery).ToTraceString)

   Console.ReadLine()

   Console.WriteLine("All Bussiness units that have had access through application with id: {0}", 56)
   For Each projection In projections
      Console.WriteLine("   Internal suppliers: {0}", projection.IsInternalSupplier)
      For Each supplier In projection.Suppliers
         Console.WriteLine("      ID: {0}, Name: {1}", supplier.ID, supplier.Name)
      Next
    Next

 End Using
```